# how to manage username and password in a url when password already one or more @ characters

Tags: http, url, ftp

how to manage username and password in a url when username/password  already has one or more @ Characters.

url : http://username:password@localhost:9090/manager/text/list
for instance.
url : http://admin:m@n@ger@localhost:9090/manager/text/list

I also tried like  http://admin:'m@n@ger'@localhost:9090/manager/text/list
but it is not working for me.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried urlencoded values like `m%40n%40ger`?

Comment: @Maxim was about to put that as an answer

Comment: '%40' is working Thanks @Maxim